# How to make a result like following

Tags: php, mysql

I wanna create a db result as follows:

```
<div class="entries">
  <div class="page"> <a href="KimAronson-TwentySeconds59483.m4v" class="first"> Palm trees and a hot sun <br />
    <em>0:20 min</em> </a> <a href="KimAronson-TwentySeconds58192.m4v"> Playing around with toes <br />
    <em>0:20 min</em> </a> <a href="KimAronson-TwentySeconds63617.m4v"> Small lake and a bicycle <br />
    <em>0:20 min</em> </a> <a href="KimAronson-TwentySeconds64268.m4v"> Hotel Room 213 In San Fransisco <br />
    <em>0:20 min</em> </a> </div>
  <div class="page"> <a href="KimAronson-TwentySeconds67463.m4v"> Some Hebrew letters on a paper<br />
    <em>0:20 min</em> </a> <a href="KimAronson-TwentySeconds65459.m4v"> Driving Golden gate bridge <br />
    <em>0:21 min</em> </a> <a href="KimAronson-TwentySeconds70930.m4v"> Eating Sushi and being trendy <br />
    <em>0:21 min</em> </a> <a href="KimAronson-TwentySeconds72119.m4v"> Big spider web on home garden <br />
    <em>0:23 min</em> </a> </div>
  <div class="page"> <a href="KimAronson-TwentySeconds71844.m4v"> Random Miniature Characters <br />
    <em>0:21 min</em> </a> <a href="KimAronson-TwentySeconds73213.m4v"> Things on the table and hidden camera <br />
    <em>0:21 min</em> </a> <a href="KimAronson-TwentySeconds75235.m4v"> Two little girls hand in hand <br />
    <em>0:21 min</em> </a> <a href="KimAronson-TwentySeconds67463.m4v"> Hebrew writings on paper again<br />
    <em>0:20 min</em> </a> </div>
</div>
```

can anybody tell me how can I do it with following query

```
$sql = "SELECT id, video_name, video_file_name, thumbnail_image, is_default FROM videos ORDER BY is_default DESC";
            $result = mysql_query($sql);
            $num = mysql_num_rows($result);
            $per_div = ceil($num/4);
            //echo "Per Div " . $per_div;
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                echo '<div class="page">';
                    while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                        echo '<a href="KimAronson-TwentySeconds59483.m4v"> Palm trees and a hot sun <br />
    <em>0:20 min</em> </a>';    
                    }
                echo '</div>';  
            }
```

Thanks

Comment: you got to loop through $sql. :-)

Comment: yap, I did a loop and its not working :(

Comment: i think it should be $result that you need to loop through.Also can you have a var_dump() of the $result?

Comment: What code do you have for actually generating the output? You say you tried a loop. Can you post it?

Comment: @Cameron Skinner: I modified my question, you can check the loop that I'm trying to use. Thanks

Comment: @Mujahid: Well, the loop doesn't appear to use the variables `row` or `row1` at all, so you're not using the data from the SQL query. See @Balanivash's answer for an example of how to use the result data.

Comment: @Cameron Skinner: Yes its not using, but I just need to get the structure with a static data, later I can assign the values from $row[], I just need to create the structure first

Comment: @Mujahid: Then you need to be more specific about **exactly** what you are asking. What is the expected output, and what are you actually seeing? Have you thought carefully about what happens when you nest loops like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**: Assuming that you want the results in groups of four:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, video_name, video_file_name, thumbnail_image, is_default FROM videos ORDER BY is_default DESC";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$out = array('<div class="page">');
$i = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $out[] = '<a href="' . htmlspecialchars($row['video_file_name']) . '"> ' . htmlspecialchars($row['video_name']) . ' <br /><em>?:?? min</em> </a>';
    if ($i % 4 === 0) {
        $out[] = '</div>';
        $out[] = '<div class="page">';
    }
    $i++;
}
$out[] = '</div>';
print implode("\n", $out);
```

(untested)

Comment: yes, the assumption is correct. I need for links grouped into a one div, so if I have 12 links, there should be 3 divs each contain 4 links. I tried your code, but its not giving me the correct result :(, im figuring out to modify it, thanks

Comment: @Mujahid See update. Please post output (e.g., via pastebin) if it doesn't work.

Comment: Seems its working, but in the first div, it gives me only one result, so I made little change, I needed to show 3 anchor links so I assigned $i to 4 like `$i = 4` in place of `$i = 0` and I divided $i by 3, now its working perfectly. Thanks a lot for the great help that you've done

Comment: @Mujahid Yup, that did not work as intended :) Alternatively, replace `$i % 4 === 0` with `$i > 0 && $i % 4 === 0` in the `if` condition.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to try this

```
foreach ($result as $row) {
echo "<a href=".$row['video_file_path']."> ". $row['video_name']."</a>"
}
```

Comment: but I can't create get a result from this loop :(

Comment: What do you mean by result here?? If you want the links in a variable, just store it in one instead of echo

Comment: I just modified my question and add the loop that im trying, can you pls have a look at it, thanks